Python script won't rename last .xlsx file in folder
I am trying to rename a series of excel files within a folder via Python that are in .xlsx format. To rename them, I need to get some information from each workbook first. I had trouble doing this as once I would get the information, I could not rename because the file was "in use by another process" so I built this workaround. It seems to work, except for the last file in the folder always gives me that same error of the file being "in use by another process".
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime

def extract_new_file_names(folder_path):
    new_file_names = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            new_filename = extract_file_info(file_path)
            new_file_names[file_path] = new_filename
    return new_file_names

def extract_file_info(file_path):
    wb = load_workbook(filename=file_path, read_only=True)
    sheet = wb.active
    
    # Extract information from the workbook
    acronym = file_path.split("_")[0]  # Get acronym from filename
    date_cell = sheet['B4'].value  # Get date from cell B4
    gl_text = sheet['D6'].value  # Get GL text from cell D6
    
    wb.close()
    
    # Process the extracted information and return the required data
    formatted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_cell, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%m-%d-%y")  
    bank_account = gl_text.split("- ", 1)[1] 
    return f"{acronym}-{formatted_date} {bank_account} recon.xlsx"

def rename_files(new_file_names):
    for old_file_path, new_filename in new_file_names.items():
        rename_file(old_file_path, new_filename)

def rename_file(old_file_path, new_filename):

    # Rename the file
    try:
        os.rename(old_file_path, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(old_file_path), new_filename))
        print(f"File {old_file_path} renamed to {new_filename}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to rename file {old_file_path}: {e}")

folder_path = "C:\\Folder\\Path\\Is\\Here"
new_file_names = extract_new_file_names(folder_path)
rename_files(new_file_names)

I can't figure out why for just the last file, excel still seems to be running. I tried modifying the rename_file function to:
def rename_file(old_file_path, new_filename):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if "EXCEL.EXE" in proc.name():
            proc.kill()
    try:
        os.rename(old_file_path, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(old_file_path), new_filename))
        print(f"File {old_file_path} renamed to {new_filename}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to rename file {old_file_path}: {e}")

but then, oddly enough it ONLY renamed the last file and gave me the error for all the other files. I am not a programmer in any meaningful sense and am just trying to automate what is currently a very long and tedious process each month for us. Any help is appreciated.

I think one of the problems you'll hit is altering things while looping over them. I'd suggest that you check the list of changes you're planning to make before renaming it.

I was able to solve my problem using Pandas library instead. Still can't say I fully understand why this worked, but it sure felt simpler this way!:)
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
from datetime import datetime

source_dir = "C:\\File\\Path\\Here"


file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.xlsx'))

def update_file_names(source_dir):
    for file_name in file_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=None)
        #print(df)
        HOA_Id = os.path.basename(file_name).split('_')[0]
        statement_date = datetime.strptime(df.iat[3, 1], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%m-%d-%y")
        gl_text = df.iat[5, 3].split("-", 1)[1].strip()
        # Replace special characters with underscores
        HOA_Id = HOA_Id.replace("%", "_").replace("/", "_")
        statement_date = statement_date.replace("%", "_").replace("/", "_")
        gl_text = gl_text.replace("%", "_").replace("/", "_")
        new_file_name = f"{HOA_Id}-{statement_date} {gl_text} recon.xlsx"
        os.rename(file_name, os.path.join(source_dir, new_file_name))


DATA_DIR = '/Users/path/to/xlsx_dir'
OUTPUT_DIR = '/Users/path/to/xlsx_output_dir'

import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def extract_file_info(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, file_path: str) -> str:
    
    # Extract information from the workbook
    acronym = file_path.split("_")[0]  # Get acronym from filename
    date_cell = dataframe['B4'].value  # Get date from cell B4
    gl_text = dataframe['D6'].value  # Get GL text from cell D6
    
    # Process the extracted information and return the required data
    formatted_date = datetime.strptime(date_cell, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%m-%d-%y")  
    bank_account = gl_text.split("- ", 1)[1] 
    return f"{acronym}-{formatted_date} {bank_account} recon.xlsx"

def rename_xlsx_files(data_dir: str, output_dir: str) -> None:
    '''
        The function renames all the xlsx files in the data_dir and saves them in the output_dir.
        While renaming the files, the function extracts information from the workbook and uses it to rename the file.
        In this case, the date cell and text cell are used to rename the file.
        # Note: Kindly try to verify the data frame columns and cell values before using them.
    '''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
                try:
                    new_file_name = extract_file_info(df, file_path)
                    new_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, new_file_name)
                    df.to_excel(new_file_path, index=False)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error occurred while processing {file_path}: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DATA_DIR):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
                print(f"Processing {file_path}...")
                print(df.head())
                print("\n")
                print(df.columns)
                print("\n")
                print(df['Date'].values)
                print("\n")
                print(df['Date'].values[0])
            break

I tried to replicate your scenario, hope it works out, let me know if it helped you in any way.

What does this do differently apart from wrapping openpyxl in pandas?

Pandas provides a high level interface for tabular data and manipulating excel files.

Thanks for the feedback here. Unfortunately, the script you gave me to try was over my head. However, I was able to figure out an answer after seeing you used Pandas library. I printed the df and was able to navigate from there. Luckily all required fields are in the same cells on each excel wb in my case. I'll post the answer that worked for me.

I know what Pandas is and while it's an excellent library, it does not provide a high-level interface for manipulating Excel files.
